# How to know the page break in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I´m using C# to create and format a Excel spreadsheet, so I need to format (merge cells, change the font, etc) until the final of the first page. How can I know the final line of the page in the Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Make your question more specific (with code, soforth), and your question MAY at least be allowed on SO.

Comment: - 1 I wouldn't have downvoted this question and only voted to close it but 3 upvotes for not showing any efforts is just too much. :) Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will give you the last row number before every horizontal page break in an Excel worksheet:

```
foreach (Excel.HPageBreak pageBreak in worksheet.HPageBreaks)
{
    int row = pageBreak.Location.Row - 1;

    // ...
}
```