# 'Invalid Index' using Excel Interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, interop, vsto

I am getting an **Invalid Index COM Exception** when attempting to retrieve a page break item that should exist.

It appears every time I attempt to access the 3rd or higher item in an Excel.Worksheet.HPageBreaks list, it returns an invalid index error. If it's item 1 or 2, it has no problem retrieving the item and giving me the parameter I need. (I'm trying to retrieve the page break row on each page to make sure the data I am entering does not get separated at certain points.)

I have thrown in my existing code for how I am initializing this document because maybe there is some parameter I am setting that you see is conflicting, which I may not be aware of. My output is MessageBoxes.

Here is my existing code:

```
        Excel.Application xApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xWorkSheet;
        object missingVal = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xWorkBook = xApp.Workbooks.Add(missingVal);
        xWorkSheet = xWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xWorkSheet.PageSetup.Orientation =
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
        xWorkSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
        xWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 20;
        xWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
        xApp.UseSystemSeparators = false;

        xWorkSheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 25;
        xWorkSheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth = 10;
        for (int i = 3; i < 28; i++)
            xWorkSheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 1;

        var range = xWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "AB1");
        range.Merge();
        range.Font.Size = 16;
        range.RowHeight = 21;
        range.Font.Bold = true;
        range.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        range = xWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "AB2");
        range.Merge();
        range.Font.Size = 10;
        range.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

        MessageBox.Show(xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Count.ToString()); //This gives zero pagebreaks
        xWorkSheet.Cells[500, 1] = " ";
        MessageBox.Show(xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Count.ToString()); //This gives nine pagebreaks
        MessageBox.Show(xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Item[1].Location.Row.ToString()); //This returns 51
        MessageBox.Show(xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Item[2].Location.Row.ToString()); //This returns 102
        MessageBox.Show(xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Item[3].Location.Row.ToString()); //This is where it breaks with the error
```

At the bottom of the code, I verified before checking the items that there are 9 items total in pagebreaks using `xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Count.ToString()`. It just does not seem to be able to retrieve any items past item 2. Not sure if it matters, but I have tried switching

```
xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Item[3]
```

to

```
xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks[3]
```

and to

```
xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks[xWorkSheet.HPageBreaks.Count] //Success at 1 or 2 PBs only
```

and tried different placements for the space character in the excel sheets other than row 500. The

I am absolutely out of ideas and have searched for solutions, only to find an irrelevant solution posted in 2010. This is my first question ever, so if I'm missing anything, please let me know! :)

Any ideas or a solution that I may have missed?

Thanks guys.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I also attempted using a foreach loop, just like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850543/how-to-know-the-page-break-in-excel-using-c-sharp), with it again returning an invalid index error specifically pointing to the foreach-loop as the cause. I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: If you debug the code, and check the value for `xWorksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` what is the integer you get back?  `Invalid index` errors are usually that, verbatim - you're trying to reference a number higher than it thinks is present.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I already did that at the bottom of the code that I posted. It returns the value 9, so I'm referencing a number that 'should' be valid but isn't for some reason. That's why I think it's strange that item 1 and 2 return properly but not 3, even though `xWorksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` is returning 9.

Comment: To be clear - you said you had 9 items, not that the explicit `.Count` returned 9, itself.  You should [edit] that verbiage in explicitly.   I will take a look at this tomorrow, in more detail, as well.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for not being too clear verbally, I edited it at the bottom. I look forward to any possible help! Thank you! :)

Comment: Is there a place you can post the `.xlsx` file - data removed if it is proprietary information, of course.  In fact, you can remove everything except the pagebreaks, I think.

Comment: The excel workbook and worksheet is created within the C# code, so there is no existing file yet, but I can save it right before checking the `xWorksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` and post that file if that would be helpful?

Comment: That would work, yes.  Let's try that, and I'll do my own research tomorrow to assist.

Comment: Here is the [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mq8kovkgt0hexw/08.12.2016_132319.xls?dl=0) to the .xls file it generates. This is saved right after the `xWorksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` MessageBox returning 9.

Comment: +1 upvoted - I'm seeing the odd behavior you mentioned, but it fails where you see '101' returned, instead.  Nevertheless, let me look at it some, and I'll return if I find any reasoning.

Comment: This has to do with not being in `PageBreak Preview` mode.  If you make the app `.Visible` true, prior to a breakpoint, and go to `View`, and set `Page Break Preview` on, I get all of the page breaks successfully.  I'm working on a coded solution for you, meanwhile.

Comment: Figured it out, I think - check my (most recently edited) answer below.  Let me know if that didn't fix it for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you instantiate `xWorksheet`, try inserting these lines:

```
xApp.ActiveWindow.View = XlWindowView.xlPageBreakPreview;
xWorkSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = true;
xWorkSheet.DisplayAutomaticPageBreaks = true;
```

This should allow all of the Page Break values to become visible within the object, and thereby be returned properly.

The reason your count was returned as expected (9), but not found, was because the default 'view' is of the first/single page.  Hence, you had 2 page breaks, but did not see the remaining page breaks beyond the first page.

The key here is actually `xlPageBreakPreview` - but the additional two lines should give the object full visibility on any future changes, as well.

Comment: +1 upvoted (I'm too new to show though) - This works wonderfully! I would have probably never found those parameters to change. Thank you so much for the help and your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Wait, this causes another issue. I'm not sure if I should open a new question or not, because this definitely fixes this issue. However, after I set `xApp.ActiveWindow.View = XlWindowView.xlPageBreakPreview;` every time I enter any data into the excel sheet, each write per cell using `xWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, n + 1] = dataTable.Rows[i][n];` is dramatically slowed down to almost unusable speeds. Any ideas?

Comment: Open a new question, for sure.  Link to this one, as you did similarly, here, and you can earn better rep.

Comment: Remember to upvote (up arrow) if it fixed the existing issue, as well, please.  Thanks for accepting, as well.

Comment: I did and it says the upvote is recorded, but not shown publicly because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: This works!! thank you @gravity, I appreciate it. : ) What makes it difficult to troubleshoot at 32-year technology under the hood, is those pesky hidden params.